# I can't communicate with a web service using gSOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, gsoap

I'm working actually on a project where I have to create a SOC design using the Board NB3000 from Altium. One part of this project is to communicate with a given published web service. As you know in embedded project we use most of the time the pure C.

I'm trying to use gSOAP to create the needed files for my project. I managed to create the files from WSDL file.

I tried to include my files to Altium Designer and compile, the result was too much errors. I was thinking that it's something to do with the c compiler of Altium Designer so I decided to try first to communicate with the web service using pure c under Ubuntu with the compiler GCC. I have less errors. The errors are:

```
/tmp/ccgst5ir.o: In function `soap_init_LIBRARY_VERSION_REQUIRED_20809':
main.c:(.text+0x2c469): undefined reference to `namespaces'
/tmp/ccgst5ir.o: In function `soap_print_fault':
main.c:(.text+0x3ce23): undefined reference to `soap_check_faultsubcode'
main.c:(.text+0x3ce41): undefined reference to `soap_check_faultdetail'
/tmp/ccgst5ir.o: In function `soap_sprint_fault':
main.c:(.text+0x3cfa5): undefined reference to `soap_check_faultdetail'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It will be great if some one can help me to communicate with my web service using pure C. (I can send the link for the WSDL.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile defining WITH_NONAMESPACES.

Comment: Thanks for you help but I'm not sure what do you mean with " compile defining WITH_NONAMESPACES" Thank you.

Comment: You should add the define WITH_NONAMESPACES to you compilation environment. For example, if you're using gcc, the command should be:

gcc -DWITH_NONAMESPACES ...

Comment: Adding -DWITH_NONAMESPACES while compiling helped remove the first error (I managed to remove the same error as well by including the ***sopa.nsmap file to my main program). but I'm still struggling to remove the other three errors related to both functions. 'soap_print_fault' and 'soap_sprint_fault'.

Comment: i tried to communicate with the web service using c++ in visual studio 2010. i have one error : `error C2129: static function 'void soap_serializeheader(soap *)' declared but not defined`. I'm lost now i don't know if I'm not using gSOAP correctly or if it's a problem with my web service which is not compatible.